# Does Each web application has one w3wp.exe.?

Tags: iis-7, w3wp, worker-process

I am confused about the worker process. Consider if i have five web applications deployed on IIS.

And all the five web applications are handling requests from different system. Now will there be only five w3wp.exe process or is there a chance for one w3wp.exe process to handle more than one web applications ?

I guess two w3wp.exe process can share the requests of single web application.. but will the web applications share a single w3wp.exe ?

-Rahul

Answer (score 1):

Simplified answer: each "Application Pool" corresponds to an instance of `w3wp.exe` (open IIS Manager and open the "Application Pools" view).

"Web Applications" are disjoint from Websites (though each website root is a "Web Application") and exist in only one Application Pool. Consequently, a single `w3wp.exe` instance can host many websites, but also a website's sub-applications might be spread-out between multiple `w3wp.exe` instances.

...and that's before getting into the workings of "Web farm" processes.

But in short, your guess that two `w3wp.exe` instances share a single IIS "Web Application" is false.

Comment: as far as i understand .. "Web application" that u are meaning here is a "Application from app pool" . And each application will have many web sites. So the w3wp.exe gets created w.r.t the application (1 per application) but not w.r.t web sites..??